# Updating a StreamBuilder with new data in Flutter and Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am using a StreamBuilder in Flutter to get realtime updates of a firestore collection `users`. I want to filter the users by age.

```
StreamBuilder<List<User>>(
    stream: UserList(minAge, maxAge),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print(snapshot.data);
    }
);
```

Basically the underlying firestore query is just a simple `where` query.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('age', isGreaterThan: minAge)
        .where('age', isLessThan: maxAge)
        .snapshots();
```

Every time the user changes the values of `minAge` or `maxAge` in the UI, the StreamBuilder receives those new parameters and gets updated. Does this cause a new query every time? If yes, will this query fetch all objects from the database every time or will that fetch only new objects and the rest from my local cache?

Comment: Please edit the question to show where the query is actually being made.  What you have right now doesn't directly involve Firestore at all.  Is it buried behind CarList?  If so, edit the question to show that code.

Comment: I edited the entire example in favor of better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code will make a new query every time minAge or maxAge changes.  The query cannot be updated with dynamically changing filters.  The query will not use the cache unless the app is offline, or you direct the query at the cache only (which is not a good idea unless you know that all possible documents are already cached).